# Redactor plugin for Bootstrap Responsive Image

Tags: plugins, redactor

Doing a quick redactor plugin to added a class to images after upload. Based on the docs, `imageUpload` should be the callback used.

The plugin loads, but am I doing this wrong:

```
if (!RedactorPlugins) var RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.responsiveimage = function () {
  return {
    init: function()
    {
      var that = this;
      console.log("loaded");
    },
    imageUpload: function(image, json){
      console.log(image);
      image.addClass("img-responsive");    
    }   
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who find this, After some more digging into Redactor, looks like Craft overrides the original button to accommodate for sources and transforms in `RichTextInput.js` at  `onImageButtonClick` - line 261.

```
onImageButtonClick: function()
{
    this.redactor.selection.save();

    if (typeof this.assetSelectionModal == 'undefined')
    {
        this.assetSelectionModal = Craft.createElementSelectorModal('Asset', {
            storageKey: 'RichTextFieldType.ChooseImage',
            multiSelect: true,
            sources: this.assetSources,
            criteria: { locale: this.elementLocale, kind: 'image' },
            onSelect: $.proxy(function(assets, transform)
            {
                if (assets.length)
                {
                    this.redactor.selection.restore();
                    for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++)
                    {
                        var asset = assets[i],
                            url   = asset.url+'#asset:'+asset.id;

                        if (transform)
                        {
                            url += ':'+transform;
                        }

                        this.redactor.insert.node($('<img src="'+url+'" />')[0]);
                        this.redactor.code.sync();
                    }
                    this.redactor.observe.images();
                }
            }, this),
            closeOtherModals: false,
            transforms: this.transforms
        });
    }
    else
    {
        this.assetSelectionModal.show();
    }
}
```

Ended up using [Retcon Twig filters plugin](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft) to add the class:

```
{{ entry.body|retconAttr('img', {class: 'img-responsive'}) }}
```